# How to get a row number for a particular element Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

There is a table with multiple rows.

I am locating an element of this table using sccSelector

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector...........);
```

This element belongs to some table row, let's say row 5.
How can I get this row's number?

```
int myElementRowNumber = ???
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about a table row.  Its not natively possible, and unless sibling elements contain text that have the number of the row, its not going to be easy either.  However, if you do want help on writing it, we need some HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `rows = myElement.findElement(By.xpath("ancestor::table[1]"))` to locate the table. Then you can use `table.findElements( By.xpath("./tbody/tr"))` to get all rows.

Use another `row = myElement.findElement(By.xpath("ancestor::tr[1]"))` to get the row element.

Now it's simply:

```
int myElementRowNumber = rows.indexOf( row );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the row No of the row where that particular value exist :

```
public String rowNo(String value)
{
   WebElement table =driver.findElement(By.id("tableId"));
   WebElement tbody=table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
   List<WebElement> rows=tbody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
   ArrayList<String> ListOdIds=new ArrayList<>();
   String rowNo="";
   for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++)
   {
     WebElement row = tbody.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='tableId']/tbody/tr["+(i+1)+"]"));
     if(row.getText().trim().contains(value))
     {
        rowNo=Integer.toString(i+1); 
            break;
     }

   }

   return rowNo;
}
```

Comment: Here first we get all the rows from the table and check if the row contains string value in it. It will gives the row no of that row which contains the value String.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **JavaScriptExecuter**. The following code will work for you.

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
 int myElementRowNumber = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].cellIndex;",myElement);
```